# Conflict between webView.ontouch and button.onclick

Tags: java, android, webview, touch-event

I have a `webView` and on this `webView` a `button`. I catch a touch event on the `webview` like this : `webView.setOnTouchListener(this);`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (ADS_VIDEO.contains(v.getId()) && v.getId() == R.id.webView
                && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            intentVideo = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    AdVideoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentVideo);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I also have this for my button :

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

My problem is when I click on the `button`, the event for the `webView` is launched and not the event linked to the button.

**Update :**

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dip"
android:id="@+id/relativeForWeb" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
     />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="42dip"
    android:layout_height="42dip"
    android:text="x" 
    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>


<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your layout.xml please?

Comment: I just updated my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the WebView comes after the Button in your layout.xml, it lays **above** it (RelativeLayout sets the z-order of its views depending on the order they are in the layout.xml).
And because the webview is above the button, it gets the touch event first and consumes it.

Simply move the webview declaration before the button declaration in your layout.xml and you should be good.

Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dip"
android:id="@+id/relativeForWeb" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
     />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="42dip"
    android:layout_height="42dip"
    android:text="x" 
    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```